# app won't load, says another copy already running

Tags: 18.04, gnome, launcher, freeze

When I try to open Audacity, I get the message that "The system has detected that another copy of Audacity is running.  Running two copies of Audacity simultaneously may cause data loss or cause your system to crash."  But I can't detect another copy.  This tends to happen, and not just with Audacity, after the system has frozen and I have had to reboot with programs open and running.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. On an HP with Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3710 @ 1.60GHz × 4, 64 bit

Comment: How have you checked for another running copy of Audacity (and other applications)? Are you using the system monitor or a command in Terminal? 

Comment: Using the system monitor.  I check .audacity-data under my User acct and found nothing except  records of past sessions.